# Google Analytics - Conversion path and attribution model by transaction id?

Tags: google-analytics

I am using GA free version. Is it possible to retrieve the conversion path (e.g. cpc -> organic -> direct -> success payment) of a particular transaction ID?

That would be helpful to analyze our marketing channel performance for particular campaigns.
Thx

Answer (score 0):

No. The transaction id is not a valid [dimension for the multichannel](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/dimsmets/) api so you cannot use it in filters (and mcf does not support segmentation to the best of my knowledge, so you can't do it via the interface either).